# Security issue with  WebService [Get] Requests?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, security, csrf

*After reading the famous (and only) [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx) about trying to explain why `asmxs` should NOTallow Get requests
so we shouldn't use : `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]` , I still I have a question :*

Why ?

Web service  , as its name is a service  , he doesn't suppose to care if it's GET or POST :

Even if a person do a CSRF : like  embedding in his malicious site :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://contoso.com/StockService/Stock.asmx/GetQuotes?symbol=msft" />
```

so what ?

Via asmx POV - it is just a normal request.

Can someone please spot for me the problem with example ?

### edit

there are many problems solved with new browsers.
this [link](http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2011/05/30/json-hijacking/) shows some other methods which should be tested in new browsers.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question but `ASMX does support HTTP GET requests. However, due to a change in default security policy in the .NET Framework, you must enable it in your web.config file: /configuration/system.web/webServices/protocols/add/@name = "HttpGet"` from msdn forums by john.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON hijacking is briefly explained in [this article](http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2012/09/json-hijacking-demystified.html).

Let's suppose that you have a web service that returns a list of credit card numbers to the currently authenticated user:

```
[{"id":"1001","ccnum":"4111111111111111","balance":"2345.15"},
 {"id":"1002","ccnum":"5555555555554444","balance":"10345.00"},
 {"id":"1003","ccnum":"5105105105105100","balance":"6250.50"}]
```

Here's how the attack could be performed:

1. Get an authenticated user to visit a malicious page.
2. The malicious page will try and access sensitive data from the application that the user is logged into. This can be done by embedding a script tag in an HTML page since the same-origin policy does not apply to script tags. `<script src="http://<json site>/json_server.php"></script>`. The browser will make a GET request to `json_server.php` and any authentication cookies of the user will be sent along with the request.
3. At this point while the malicious site has executed the script it does not have access to any sensitive data. Getting access to the data can be achieved by using an object prototype setter. In the code below an object prototypes property is being bound to the defined function when an attempt is being made to set the `"ccnum"` property.

   ```
   Object.prototype.__defineSetter__('ccnum',function(obj) {
       secrets = secrets.concat(" ", obj); 

   });
   ```

At this point the malicious site has successfully hijacked the sensitive financial data (`ccnum`) returned by `json_server.php`.

There are also other forms of JSON hijacking techniques which do not rely on the browser support for the `__defineSetter__` function. That's just one way to conduct the attack but there are many others as described in [this article](http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2011/05/30/json-hijacking/) such as `Array constructor clobbering`, `UTF-7`, `ES5 functionality`.

For this reason, GET requests returning JSON are disabled by default in ASP.NET.

Comment: Darin thats correct. Many people think that ajax can not do cross site requests. Well it can do  , but can't get response. Ive tested it with my domain. my localhost jquery ajax went to ASHX (in my real domain) and DID increased DB column by 1(operation at ASHX's page load). it is only CANT GET THE RESPONSE !

Comment: @RoyiNamir, there are techniques that actually allow to access the JSON response: `__defineSetter__ `, `Array constructor clobbering`, `UTF-7 encoding`, `ECMAScript 5 getters and setters`, ... JSONP simplifies this by wrapping the JSON into a javascript function call, but it could be achieved even with plain JSON. That's why JSON hijacking exists and is very dangerous. Of course if your site doesn't return any sensitive data you shouldn't be concerned. You just need to be aware of the risks.

Comment: I understood most of your answer : The part where i'm stuck : _Getting access to the data can be achieved by using an object prototype setter._ ok so the hacking site has executed this code (point #3) but how does he has access to the JSON ? his BAD.com site had a script tag to GOOD.com but BAD.com cant see the response from  Good.com...no ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, he puts this code on his site. As you can see in this code he subscribes to an event which will be invoked when a property is being set on any javascript object. This event is the anonymous function. So when the browser sends the GET request from the `<script>` tag, since the server returns JSON, the browser will execute the setters of each property! So the anonymous function will be called everytime a property is being set. In this function all the hacker has to do is build an array containing the values.

Comment: oh sh** , I confused. cross domain ajax results dont have access to browser. script tag of course has access. But still when writing `<script src="http://<json site>/json_server.php"></script>` does the browser actually recieve the json  result and  calls `__defineSetter__` ? (just verifying) thanks  a lot.

Comment: Yes, if the browser supports the `__defineSetter__` method it will call it.

Comment: I created a sample but its not alerting http://jsbin.com/afiyep/2/edit ( need to save it as html file)

Comment: According to your link it suppose to work. ( the strange thing is  : when calling ths json script  - it is being set to ____ ? ) thats why the alert doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Well if you follow the article that is then linked in the one you provided which can be found here: http://ajax.asp.net/docs/overview/AsynchronousLayerOverview.aspx, you can then read on and the only reason it specifically specifies is this:

> GET requests are not recommended for method calls that modify data on
>   the server or that expose critical information. In GET requests, the
>   message is encoded by the browser into the URL and is therefore an
>   easier target for tampering. For both GET and POST requests, you
>   should follow security guidelines to protect sensitive data.

Comment: encoding the request into the url is not the main issue. post can be also tracked.

Comment: I was just stating what the documentation had to say as to why they are unsafe as the question was asked but I agree there are many other security measures that should be relied on vs just using POST over GET.